# What's the meaning of "for" in "dark for the sunrise"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Different from the articles, which have relatively coherent contexts to help you better understand them, the meaning of a lyric of a song is quite separated so that sometimes I couldn't fully comprehend it.

Take the song *[We'll Meet Again](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric-lf/2319969/TheFatRat/We%27ll+Meet+Again)* by TheFatRat for example. The lyrics, "dark for the sunrise, clouds for a blue sky" and other similar kinds, make no sense to me, even though I know "for" has carried so many meanings.

Comment: Please put in actual sentences with the preposition for. Thanks. Your question is hard to read and hard to understand.

Comment: sorry, I'm indented to say that some lyrics of songs are hard for me, a non-native English speak, to comprehend, compared with articles, which have specific context for understanding.

Comment: Song lyrics aren't always meant to be clearly understood. Sometimes they just paint a mental picture or generate a feeling in you. If you can't parse a particular lyric, assume it's not meaningful in the normal way, which is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Song lyrics and verse often use compressed or non-standard grammar for emotional or metrical effect. They often aim at emotional rather than logical effects, and it is not always possible, even for a good native speaker, to determine exactly what meaning is intended.

In  this case, the stanza referred to is:

> Dark for the sunrise
> Clouds for a blue sky
> Space for the traveling star
> Strong from the inside
> You're still my lifeline
> I feel you wherever you are

The exact meaning of this, particularly of the first two lines, is not, in my view, fully clear. I suggest that those lines are intended as examples of contrast, saying that darkness leads to or is followed by sunrise, and a cloudy sky by a clear blue one; further I think this is being used as a metaphor for romantic problems that the speaker hopes will pass away. The word "for" here is not being used with any very exact meaning, in my view, it simply connects the two contrasting concepts.

In future for analysis of song lyrics and verse, you might try Literature.SE.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and patience. By the way, I have just read a comment above, which suggests that I didn't convey my thoughts clearly, but it seems that you have fully comprehended my words. Is it because you had corrected my expression in your mind and inferred what I was trying to say?  If it's the reason, could you give me some suggestions or simply tell me where I did wrong?  Once again, I want to express my sincere appreciation for helping me further my English study.

Comment: I am not sure why @Lambie, who is a very experienced poster here, found your question hard to understand. It may have been the opening "Different from the articles" which for a moment i thought referred to **grammatical** articles, rather than texts. Also, it is usually helpful here to give a full sentence or more as an example. By the way, in that sentence you should have written "Aside from articles" omitting the word "the", because you were not referring to any specified or particular articles.

Comment: The mistake "the" is truly an important problem that I should take seriously(I have overlooked this problem many times). But I noticed that you revised my original expression " different from “with” apart from “. Why is that? I was attempting to make a contrast between articles and lyrics, yet "aside from" seems to just convey a meaning that one thing is excluded from the other without being compared to it. Or did I misunderstand what you said? Sorry for troubling you again.

Comment: @wonderfulwond I rephrased your text because "Different from" is not normally used in the way you used it. but on re-reading "aside" was not the best choice for a substitute. Perhaps "In contrast with" would have been better. Also "*...meaning of a lyric of a song is quite separated*" is a rather non-standard use of  "separated", but that is too large an issue to deal with in a comment. Perhaps it could be a separate question.