# What is wrong with my original sentence?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

In  the question [What's the meaning of "for" in "dark for the sunrise"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/312052/whats-the-meaning-of-for-in-dark-for-the-sunrise) I wrote

> The meaning of a lyric of a song is quite separated so that sometimes
> I couldn't fully comprehend it.

This is a line that I wrote to ask a question, which is trying to express that there are many lyrics in a song, and each of the lyrics has its own meaning and the relation between them is quite obscure.

While being informed that:

> Also "...meaning of a lyric of a song is quite separated" is a rather non-standard use of "separated", but that is too large an issue to deal with in a comment.

I want to know how I should express the meaning that I want with "lyric of a song is quite separated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the word "lyric" is incorrect. We use "lyric" or "lyrics" to mean the words of a song. We don't use "A lyric" to mean one word or one line from a song. You don't say "there are many lyrics in a song". You probably mean "There are many lines in the lyric of a song".

The construction "the meaning ... is separated" is not idiomatic. You say that two things are separated, but not one thing. The participle form "separated" also suggests that they were together, but someone has moved them apart. Again this doesn't fit the meaning.

What you probably mean is that the meaning of each line in the song is separate from the other lines.